# How do I add a CiviCRM Contact as a User in Wordpress without them being a Member and using the WP Member Sync Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, civicontact

Our organisation has one Membership type in CiviCRM, and we have that syncing with a Group in Wordpress using the CiviCRM Wordpress Member Sync plugin. All is well.

We also have a Guest sign-up form (using a Civi Profile with WP account creation required) which adds them as a Contact in Civi and a User in WP, they also get added to a Civi Group (Guests) which is synced to a WP Group (Guests). All is well. [Lapsed Members should also move to this WP Group (Guests) until they renew their membership when they should get removed. Yet to be tested]

However, we sometimes need to manually add Contacts in CiviCRM ourselves (say VIP speaker for an event), and although we add these to the synced Guests group, they don't get added in WP, of course, as a WP User account is not created when we add the Contact manually in CiviCRM.

Is there a box to tick / dropdown to select for a Contact or multiple Contacts along the lines of: 'Create WP User Account from Contact'?

I have CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync plugin installed.

I truly hope this is not a stupid question...

Cheers, Tracy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'CIVICRM_WP_PROFILE_SYNC_BULK', true );
```

Then select some contacts and use the “Actions” dropdown to “Create WordPress Users from Contacts”.

Comment: For those (like me :-( ) that didn't read the question carefully enough and jumped to the answer... This setting is part of the "CiviCRM WordPress Profile Sync" plugin so that needs to be installed and activated before the action shows up.

Comment: Thank you @christian-wach. It created the user in WP. One thing though, I thought the profile sync plugin kept the first name and last name of the civiccm contact as well as the email. It has created the username in WP (mrjoeblogs), it also filled in the Nickname (mrjoeblogs), has the correct Display name in the dropdown (Mr Joe Blogs), but the First Name and Last Name fields are blank. Is this the expected result or have I missed something?

Comment: A thought: I installed profile sync via the WP plugin directory---version 0.3.2. Should I upload the 0.3.3 version from GitHub?

Comment: @TracyShorrock Hmm, yes, you appear to be right about First Name and Last Name - it's a while since I looked at this functionality. I'll post a fix shortly.

Comment: In the meantime, just re-save any migrated Contacts in CiviCRM and their WordPress First Name and Last Name will be populated.

Comment: Okay, I've just released 0.3.3 on the WordPress Plugin Directory - should fix the issue.

Comment: Wow! That's above and beyond for a Friday :) I will update this evening. And thanks for the re-saving tip.

Comment: I've also discovered that is doable per contact from the contact summary in the `Action` menu: User account. Great feature I was looking for. Thanks Christian

Comment: This tip is great. 
For a convenient usage, use the Advanced search form and list Contacts with "CMS user" attribute to "No".

Then, use the bulk action.